# How to draw these two tables?

Tags: tables

I need to draw a two tables given below :
[image]
This is what I have tried

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|@{}c@{}|}\hline
&
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \\
 \\\hline
 \\
 \\
\end{tabular}
\tabularnewline\hline

&
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\\
 \\\hline
\\
\\

\end{tabular}
\tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: i would rather draw it as `tikz` image.

Comment: how with tikz image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me is simpler to draw those tables as `tikz` picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1mm and 11mm,
tabnod/.style = {rectangle split,
                 rectangle split parts=5, rectangle split empty part height=1em,
                 draw, minimum width=8em}
                        ]
\node (n1) [tabnod, label=below:$A$]{};
\node (n2) [above right=of n1]      {$x$};
\node (n3) [tabnod, label=below:$B$,
            below right=of n2]      {};
\draw[semithick,-Straight Barb]
      (n2) edge [out=265, in=5]     (n1.three east)
      (n2)  to  [out=275, in=175]   (n3.four west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1mm and 11mm,
tabnod/.style = {rectangle split,
                 rectangle split parts=5, rectangle split empty part height=1em,
                 draw, minimum width=8em}
                        ]
\node (n1) [tabnod, label=below:$A$]{};
\node (n2) [above right=of n1]      {$x$};
\node (n3) [tabnod, label=below:$B$,
            below right=of n2]      {};
\draw[semithick,-Straight Barb]
      (n2) edge [out=265, in=5, "$g$"'] (n1.three east)
      (n2)  to  [out=275, in=175,"$h$"] (n3.four west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (n2) edge [out=265, in=5]     (n1.three east) in this edge I want to write g

Comment: ups, a forgot on this two letters, but they are simple to add :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be your starting point. I am afraid that you will have tweak the values based on the actual scenario.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c@{}c@{}c}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      \hline
      \\\hline
      \\\hline
      \\\hline
      \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, shorten <=-1.75ex, node distance=20.0mm, auto]
  \node (x) {\raisebox{1.50ex}{$X$}};
  \node (x1) [below left of=x] {};
  \node (x2) [below right of=x] {};
  \path (x) edge[bend left] node [above] {$g$} (x1);
  \path (x) edge[bend right] node [above] {$h$} (x2);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      \hline
      \\\hline
      \\\hline
      \\\hline
      \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

[PGF Man­ual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) is the ultimate guide on `tikz`. It also comes with a
*[min­i­mal in­tro­duc­tion](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf)* version.